# Cassandra client side partition key calculation to save disk space

Tags: cassandra, cql, datastax-java-driver

I have a table that has a compound partition key made up of five large fields.

I noticed that the SSTable index files for this table are very large due to the size of these five fields.

I don't actually need to retrieve the values of these fields from my table, so to save space I'd like to hash them in the client to a single value and then use that single value as the partition key, the same way Cassandra does when it maps a compound partition key to a single token value.

So I'm wondering if there is a function in the java driver or some java library function I can use in my clients to generate this single value.

I guess the type I want to use is uuid, so I'm looking for a function I can pass N values to and get a uuid back out to then use as my partition key value.  Anyone know of a good way to do that?

Comment: I don't know for uuid, but you could simply use the hash function offered by the common-lang package of the Apache library HashCodeBuilder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have your tried enabling compression and see how that works with your current data model?

Using a hash value as your partition key will be prone to hash collisions. The actual chance that hashes collide depends on the used algorithm. Solid algorithms such as 128 bit [murmur3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MurmurHash) will drastically lower chances, but they might still happen, in which case you might see data swaps in your application.

Comment: I have LZ4 compression on for the table.  How does Cassandra itself avoid collisions?  I basically want to calculate the token value Cassandra would calculate and give it to Cassandra for the partition key.  I'm using the Murmur3Partitioner, and that appears to hash things to -2^63 to +2^63-1.  So could I use a bigint for a partition key and generate a murmur3hash from my 5 values?  Or would that be prone to collisions?  I can't have collisions.

Comment: Hash collisions are not relevant for Cassandra, as generated tokens doesn't have to be unique. The reason for using hashes at all as token values is to get a even distribution of tokens across the token ring.

Comment: Oh, I guess it won't work then.  I thought the token value controlled how the data was stored rather than just selecting which machine owns it.